# Cannot read registry in VS2010 Setup Project Launch Condition

Tags: .net, registry, windows-installer, setup-project, launch-condition

the installer won't proceed please help. I believe I did everything right but I don't know what seems to be wrong in the registry settings. Am I missing something?

I've uploaded a photo of my case, please help:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/atPJO.jpg

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution works for me! Please note the one and only comment in the article:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cristib/archive/2012/09/28/10354108.aspx

Not deleting the question in case other people encounter this problem. :)